# custom 404 error htaccess doesn't work on apache 2

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, http-status-code-404

I've tried doing this with a .htaccess file on Apache and just couldn't get it to redirect to a custom 404 page. It would just keep on using the default apache 404 page.

This is what I've done:

I've put .htaccess file and a custom 404 file (page-not-found.php) into my home directory where index.php is.

This is the line that's in .htaccess file:
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.php

I also tried the full document path:
ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/htdocs/page-not-found.php

I've made sure that in '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default' and '/etc/apache2/sites-available/default' 'AllowOverride'  is set to 'All' as below:

```
    <Directory /var/www/htdocs/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I made sure that AccessFileName in httpd.conf is .htaccess

I restarted apache after every change.

None of this made it work, it still uses the default apache 404 file.
Anoying thing is that this worked on a vritual site on the same server, but wouldn't work on the default site. Separate but same issue: I also can't get it to work on localhost on my own pc.

(Arggghhhhhhh!!!!!!!!!!)

What am I missing?

Comment: past the code of .htaccess also. have you added this thing in your .htaccess file ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html

Comment: The code of the .htaccess is within my post above

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled the mod ?

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

you will need to restart apache again after installing

Comment: This made no difference. Bare in mind that what I've said I've done in my original post worked on the virtual site on the same server, but not on default site. Thanks for your help